# Cannot build wheel error when trying to install openAI gym

Tags: python, macos, reinforcement-learning

I saw that failure to build wheel atari-py, pachi-py was a common problem people ran into when installing openai gym in mac. And the solutions suggested in them was to use export commands export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11 
export SDKROOT=/path/to/Mac10.11SDK before making the build. I tried the given suggestions and yet I am finding the same error when trying to install full openai gym. Can anyone help me in getting around this issue ?

Comment: ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting

I get the above error before the installation gets collapse.

Answer (score 1):

verify  if you already installed cmake, if not you can do it with:
**$ brew install cmake**

and later you can install atari-py:
**$ pip install atari-py**

Reference in oficial GitHub [repo](https://github.com/openai/atari-py)